# Understanding Common Lisp do syntax

Tags: syntax, lisp, common-lisp, do-loops

I have a little problem to understand do in lisp

I have this code :

```
(defun iota-b (n)
  (do ((x 0 (+1 x))
      (u '() (cons x u)))
      ((> x n) (nreverse u))))
```

> (iota-b 5)
>
> (0 1 2 3 4 5)

In documentation there is the "do" basic template is:

```
(do (variable-definitions*)
    (end-test-form result-form*)
 statement*)
```

I really don't understand where is my body in my function iota-b
For me it's

> (u '() (cons x u)))

apparently not, why we put (u '() (cons x u))) in the variable-definitions ?

Comment: Correct indenting would have hinted at the problem. I suggest not editing the post with respect to that, because the original indentation makes it clear, where the question may stem from.

Comment: Is it more Lispy to wrestle with parentheses than to give in to the Devil and do `(loop for x to 3 collect x)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the variable definitions of the form `var init [step]`

```
((x 0 (+1 x))
 (u '() (cons x u)))
```

this increments `x` in every iteration and builds with `(cons x u)` the `u` list as `(5 4 3 2 1 0)`.

The end test

```
(> x n)
```

The result form

```
(nreverse u)
```

reverses the list `(5 4 3 2 1 0)` to the given result.

And then you have an empty body.

You can of course modify the do loop to

```
(do ((x 0 (+1 x))
     (u '()))
    ((> x n) (nreverse u))
  (setq u (cons x u)))
```

this will give the same result.

Comment: @Martialp The code in your question is not indented properly. Do you understand what's going on after fixing the indentation (hit `Tab` in any good editor)?

Comment: yep, i just see that ! well thx, i think i understand, thx a lot !

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun iota-b (n)
  (do 
      ; var init step
      ((x   0    (1+ x))       ; var 1
       (u   '()  (cons x u)))  ; var 2

      ;test    result
      ((> x n) (nreverse u))   ; end ?

    ; body comes here
    ; this DO loop example has no body code
    ; the body code is optional

    ))
```